# Method to find the object rotation/scale/position using opencv

Tags: opencv

I want to find the match template including rotation, scale and position.But cvMatchTemplate doesn't provide these details, It detects only the position.

I have seen the examples using chess board. But I want to implement the same example with my custom image.

Thanks for help.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can not use cvMatchTemplate for that. If the object you are looking for has different scale or rotation then cvMatchTemplate will fail. You better look for other techniques like [Feature Detection](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an arbitrary affine matrix to transform one image to best match another you can use:

```
Mat M = estimateRigidTransform(img1,img2,true);
```

If you want to get the affine matrix that will only translate/rotate/scale one image to best match another you can use:

```
Mat M = estimateRigidTransform(img1,img2,false);
```

This isn't quite the same as using templates however, and it assumes that the two images are of the same object (more or less).